# LoginForm uses http:// to submit while site is on https, how to make it https?

Tags: frontend, login, ssl

My customer login form, forgot password and all these forms are not working as they are redirected to same page with an error in console "form is using http whereas it should be https".

I altered from developer toolbar and make the action attribute value of form starting with https:// and then it worked fine.

Am wondering how to make it https?

BTW it is magento 1.5 and I know it is very OLD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the according templates (or copy the base templates into your theme folder) and replace the form action url to use secure url, like:

```
Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login',array('_secure'=>true))

Mage::getUrl('',array('_secure'=>true))
```

Comment: <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">

Comment: This is the form action url, where do you want me to make changes?

Comment: Honestly I'm not familiar with v.1.5 but try to replace <?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?> with <?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login',array('_secure'=>true)) ?> If this doesn't work replace customer/account/login with the original url query